# How to count the number of times I earned 200 daily reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm interested to get the [Epic](https://serverfault.com/badges/73/epic) badge. Is there another way than go to my profile -> Reputation tab -> and count one by one?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com)! In fact someone has already [written that query](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/39674/days-hit-rep-cap)

Comment: When I ran that query it gave results that conflict with what is shown in my rep history, including an entry of 270 that doesn't appear in my history, nor which I have any recollection of.

Answer (score 4):

You can see your reputation history by visiting: https://serverfault.com/reputation

Since SE uses cookies, [`Cookies Export/import`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-exportimport/) Firefox extension may be useful:

```
$ wget --load-cookie cookies.txt https://serverfault.com/reputation
```

`$ awk '$1 == "--" && $4 >= +200 { print $0; s += 1 } END { print "Total: ", s }' reputation`

Comment: Using the Data Explorer (http://data.stackexchange.com) and our API (https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)  are much better ways to go about this.

Comment: @Zypher looking at the `/reputation` page has got to be the easiest way to see, and it's semi-live data instead of the weekly data dump.

Comment: @chris the api is live (but not thaat easy) after the sql 2012 migration next weekend data.se will be live as well

Comment: @Zypher Oh, didn't know about that. I need to read up on all that.

Comment: @ChrisS Weekly?  data.SE hasn't been updated for two months!

Comment: It hasn't been updated for like 5 months ..